# Problem with displaying file path in Finder's Get Info -> Where

Tags: finder, mojave, path

I occasionally need to check some file's location and copy it to the clipboard. I used to use Finder -> Cmd-I then I used to copy the content of "Where" section.

Ever since updating to macOs Mojave, the format of the path displayed in the "Where" section has changed. Instead of "/" forward slash character now I see "triangle" character.

[image: triangle in path]

How to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I also find this problem and haven't found a solution. This is a really bad change and It seems that Apple haven't fixed this issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can select the file and press <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the pathname to the clipboard.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252179/192890

You can also use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + right click in macOS Mojave (copy as pathname will replace copy file in get info modal). Little change but I just found it. Still works on networked drives too.

Comment: Note: Running Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.6, and Control is unnecessary. I right click on the file, then hold Option to get the modal menu with the pathname option.

Comment: @jvriesem Not working for me (mojave) after many attempts: but the original answer here does work

Comment: @javadba: Odd! I'm also running Mojave (10.14.6), and the following does work for me: 1) Right click on the file in Finder (on the desktop, in a folder) to bring up the menu. While the menu is open, hold Option, and the menu options change slightly. One of the options for me (for a file called `filename.txt`) is `Copy "filename.txt" as Pathname`. If that doesn't work for you, what numeric version of MacOS are you using?

Answer (score 12):

1. Right Click on Folder/File
2. Hold down the Option key
3. Select Copy "[filename]" as pathname
4. Paste to wherever you need it

[image]

Comment: This one actually works

Answer (score -1):

Even though the Info window shows triangles, selecting and copying the text will copy the path with slashes.

That said, [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339428) is probably a better solution.

Comment: On high sierra, it copies with slashes, but on mojave it seems to copy weird triangle characters instead of slashes.

Comment: I confirm that on Mojave it copies with the triangles.